# How to filter results using equalTo in firebase REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the firebase realtime database rest api to stream changes to messages.json. Each message has this structure.

```
{
    "sender": "senderID",
    "recipient": "recipientID",
    "message": {
        "event": "event",
        "info": "info"
    },
    "time": "datetime"
}
```

Each messages is added using a post, so they are each given a unique ID, like `-Nl9oB6Wwp5B1FHqQH1I`.

I call `https://PROJECTID.firebaseio.com/messages.json?auth=IDTOKEN` to get all messages.

I would like to use equalTo to filter on recipient, but I can't find any examples to filter on the subfield.
`https://PROJECTID.firebaseio.com/messages.json?auth=IDTOKEN&equalTo=???`

How can I use equalTo to filter and return only documents with a specific recipient ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering) with the Realtime Database REST API, you need to specify an `orderBy` and an `equalTo` parameter.

I reproduced your data structure on https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/77631409.json as:

```
{
  "key1" : {
    "message" : {
      "event" : "event",
      "info" : "info"
    },
    "recipient" : "recipientID",
    "sender" : "senderID",
    "time" : "datetime"
  },
  "key2" : {
    "message" : {
      "event" : "event",
      "info" : "info"
    },
    "recipient" : "otherRecipientID",
    "sender" : "senderID",
    "time" : "datetime"
  },
  "key3" : {
    "message" : {
      "event" : "event",
      "info" : "info"
    },
    "recipient" : "recipientID",
    "sender" : "senderID",
    "time" : "datetime"
  }
}
```

Now I can filter on the `recipient` property being `recipientID` with: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/77631409.json?orderBy=%22recipient%22&equalTo=%22recipientID%22

This returns `key1` and `key3`, but not `key2` as that has a `recipient` value of `otherRecipientID`.

Comment: %22 is a double quote and is required for each value in the URL

Comment: I had to enable indexing on the recipient field: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data